# Turn off smooth scrolling in Office 365

Tags: outlook-on-the-web

In the Outlook component of Microsoft Office 365, when jumping between mails in a conversation, the email pane scrolls back and forth at varying speed for a second or two until it settles on its target.

How can I turn off this graphical annoyance and get a snappy transition to the target?

More generally, I would like to turn off any and all smooth scrolling anywhere in Office 365 which I'm surely yet to discover.

I'm open to a solution that involves a userscript, but I'd prefer something that works in all main browsers including IE 8.

Answer (score -1):

I got this from a blog help article and it stopped Excel 365 from animating the transition from one cell to the new one I was clicking, which is similar to the problem you are describing:

1. Right click on My Computer icon on the Desktop and choose Properties option OR just hit Win+Pause
2. In the System window click the "Advanced System Settings" link in the left pane
3. Click Continue button if prompted by UAC
4. Now click Settings button under "Performance" section
5. Select "Custom:" and check the option "Animate controls and elements inside windows" to disable animations
6. Click OK button
7. Click OK button in the System Properties window -- Done.

Comment: Can you summarize the steps that the blog post recommends within the body of your answer?  Thanks.

Comment: As requested, done.

Comment: Thank you!  Eventually the other person should remove their downvote.

Comment: What does this have to do with the Office 365 **web application**? This may be useful in the Windows application, where [I had the same problem](http://superuser.com/questions/194209/turning-off-smooth-scrolling-in-outlook-2010), though it seems that this didn't work for Outlook 2010; I'm not in front of a Windows machine right now to check for the current version.